# AX2012 CU6 : SYSSEQUENCES.NextVal for USERDATAAREAFILTER table is maxed out

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

We are running Dynamics AX 2012 CU6.

About once a week, users are reporting that they cannot log into the application (usually in the morning).  After investigations, it always seems to be the same issue:

In table SYSSEQUENCES, the value of the field NextVal for the table USERDATAAREAFILTER is maxed out.  When double checking in the USERDATAAREAFILTER table itself, the highest RecId is far from being set to the maximum value.

The solution itself is quite easy as we simply update the SYSSEQUENCES.NextVal to MAX(RecId) + 1 FROM USERDATAAREAFILTER ...  And then all of a sudden, every users can log in immediately.

Do you guys have any idea why is this happening?  Have you seen anything like it?

Because this issue occurs in these system tables (and system classes), I have a hardtime understanding the cause of this problem.

Any idea is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for client-mismatches? Check the AOS event log to see if any clients are connecting with an improper kernel.

Also, have you performed an AOS restart in a while?

You could try playing with flushing the erring number sequence # cache via:

`new NumberSeqNumCache().flushCacheInternal(12345);`

`new NumberSeqNumCache().flushCache(12345);`